# Can't extract data from Intent - Firebase Push Notification

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-notifications

I'm using Firebase Notifications. For test, I send notifications from the Firebase Console. But in my `MainActivity` I can't get data, which I set in the console.

Method `onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage msg)` in `MyFirebaseService` doesn't get called (if the method didn't get called - data transfer to `MainActivity` in `Intent`). But I don't see this data in `Intent`.

For example:
[image]
And in debug:
[image]

Comment: Sorry. I'm a bit confused. Shouldn't you be using the [RemoteMessage.getData()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/messaging/RemoteMessage.html#getData()) to get the data payload? Also, do post the codes as text instead of images. Do include your `onMessageReceived()`.

Comment: @AL. - yes - it possible only if method onMessageReceived() called

Comment: I think onMessageReceived() won't be called if the app is in background. Did you check with the app in foreground ?

Comment: @ArtemShevchenko is this line of code attained after being redirected by the notification?

Comment: @MridulSKumar on my device onMessageReceived() never called. And I ask about another situation!

Comment: Is the onMessageReceived() called when the app is running ?

Answer (score 0):

If you use the console to send notification, it is not considered as payload, so if the application is running in background, the method onMessageReceived() is not called. But if the app run in foreground it does.

Here is a curl command to send a notification via curl as payload, you have to use a shell to use it.

```
curl -X POST --header "Authorization: key=<APIKEY>" --Header "Content-Type:
application/json" https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send -d '{"to":"<YourToken>","data":{"type":"notification","message":"Hello, it works"}}'
```

**Note: remove the <>.

Your onMessageReceived() method looks like this to get the data.

```
 @Override
public void onMessageReceived(final RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
 try {
       String remote_type = remoteMessage.getData().get("type");
        if (remote_type.equals("notification")){
            String message = remoteMessage.getData().get("message");
            Log.d("ReceivedData", message);
        }
    }catch(NullPointerException e){ 
    }
```